# Pyspark replace a column from another dataframe which has one column

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have a dataframe with some columns in which I want to replace one column value from another dataframe.  For me the problem is I don't have any common column so I can do joins, etc. I simply would like to drop column if dataframe1, and replace with the same column value from 2nd dataframe, can you please help me.

I have tried union, but its adding rows from both dataframes which is not desired.

I am providing herewith a sample dataframe for reference please:

```
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("USA","Unknown"), ("UK","Unknown"), ("Canada","Unknown")], ["country","count"])
df1.show()
+-------+-------+
|country|  count|
+-------+-------+
|    USA|Unknown|
|     UK|Unknown|
| Canada|Unknown|
+-------+-------+

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("1000"), ("2000"), ("3000")], ["count"])
df2.show()
+-------+
|  count|
+-------+
|1000|
|2000|
|3000|
+-------+
```

Expected Result: I would like to drop/delete the count column in df1, and append it from df2.

```
+-------+-------+
|country|  count|
+-------+-------+
|    USA|1000|
|     UK|2000|
| Canada|3000|
+-------+-------+
```

Appreciate any help please.  Thanks

Comment: Am able to achieve this using Window & rank options.  Will share sample code soon.  Thanks